# how to use isc-dhcp-server in place of router dhcp

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, dhcp

i have a virtual Debian installed on my VMware running on win 7 64 bit , 
i am using a bridged connection for my virtual machine , 
i installed isc-dhcp-server and changed the `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.config` to :

```
# Sample /etc/dhcpd.conf
# (add your comments here) 

default-lease-time 600; 
max-lease-time 7200;     

option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0; 
option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255; 
option routers 192.168.1.254; 
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2; 
option domain-name "ubuntu-fr.lan"; 
option ntp-servers 192.168.1.254;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {   
       range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.100;   
       range 192.168.1.150 192.168.1.200; 
}
```

and i added eth0 to INTERFACES in `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`,

i want to use the isc-dhcp-driver to generate interfaces address,
`dhclient` command use the router dhcp server , and when i use it with -s option to use my dhcp server address (0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1) it block.

i tried `dhcpd eth0` but it tell me that there is no interface to listen or something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED ,

by default , dhclient send a broadcast request , and since we have two server set up , they will respond with a Dhcp offer so our interface will have a confusion ,

the solution is to specify the dhcp server address by the `s` option , like this :

`dhclient eth0 -s 127.0.0.1`

like this we will not send the request to broadcast but to just 127.0.0.1 ,

the `dhcp-server` must be running and listening in the given address ,

GOOD LUCK ,